# base b expansion of n algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

im reading about base b expansion of n algorithm and this book is really hard to read and understand,  i am not sure what the bottom part means...

[image]

does it return n or what ? how would you do this...thanks

```
some method (n,b)
if b == 0
    return 1
q = n
k = 0
while q does not == 0
    a[k] = q % b
    q = q / b
    k = k + 1
    return ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an implementation in C for the function. It uses a pointer as input parameter, where the output (a vector of integers) will be placed. The function also returns an integer - the logical size of the vector.

```
#include <assert.h>

int toBase(int n, int b, int* answer) {
    assert(b > 1);
    q = n
    k = 0
    while (q != 0) {
        answer[k] = q % b;
        q /= b;
        ++k;
    }
    return k;
}

int main() {
    int answer[32];
    int n = 100000;
    int b = 2;
    int answerSize = toBase(n, b, answer);

    // use answer and answerSize

    return 0;
}
```

Another way to do it (without the pointer parameter) is to allocate memory for the vector inside the function and return it, requiring the calling function to release the used memory after it has finished processing it.

In this case, you can't tell the logical size of the vector, so you have to set answer[k] to a special value (-1 here), to know where the vector ends.

```
#include <assert.h>

int* toBase(int n, int b) {
    assert(b > 1);
    int* answer = malloc(33 * sizeof(int));
    q = n
    k = 0
    while (q != 0) {
        answer[k] = q % b;
        q /= b;
        ++k;
    }
    answer[k] = -1;
    return answer;
}

int main() {
    int n = 100000;
    int b = 2;
    int *answer = toBase(n, b);

    // use answer

    free(answer);
    return 0;
}
```

A more elegant solution (in C++) is to use the STL vector class.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this algorithm is that it's creating a list of values a<sub>k</sub>, a<sub>k-1</sub>, a<sub>k-2</sub>, ..., a<sub>0</sub>.  At the very end, it wants to return that list of values and do so in a form that looks like the base-b representation of the number.

For example, if you input 33 into this algorithm and ask for its base-16 representation, the algorithm will set a<sub>1</sub> = 2 and a<sub>0</sub> = 1.  The return value of the algorithm is then the representation 21, which is a<sub>1</sub> (2) followed by a<sub>0</sub> (1).

The notation they're using is just fancy mathspeak for "return the list of values produced by this algorithm."  You can think of it as returning an array of the base-b digits of the number.

Hope this helps!